# replace the page meta and link with global meta on nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, meta-tags

Why doesn't the local configuration for meta title and description override the global configuration

The problem is that when I change the meta tags and links on the page, it removes the meta tags that are global and replaces the new meta tags. I want these meta and links to be added to the global meta and links.

In the meta tag and global links that I have, I have a part that makes the logo part of the site correct when adding a bookmark in Safari, but when I add the meta tag to my page, the photo is no longer loaded, and I think the problem is from It is that Next replaces the meta tags that are created on each page instead of the global meta tags

**this is my nuxt config code**

```
 head: {
        title: 'Flyver',
        htmlAttrs: {
          lang: 'en',
        },
        meta: [
          .........
          { charset: 'utf-8' },
          {
            name: 'viewport',
            hid: 'viewport',
            content:
              'width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no,maximum-scale=5,viewport-fit=cover',
          },
          { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
          { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' },
          {
            hid: 'apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style',
            name: 'apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style',
            content: 'black-translucent',
          },
          .........
        ],
        link: [
          .........
    
          {
            hid: 'apple-touch-icon',
            rel: 'apple-touch-icon',
            href: '/android-chrome-180x180.png?v=sf54fgh123',
            type: 'image/png',
            sizes: '180x180',
          },
          {
            hid: 'apple-touch-icon1',
            rel: 'apple-touch-icon',
            href: '/apple-touch-icon.png?v=sf54fgh123',
            type: 'image/png',
            sizes: '120x120',
          },
          .........
      },
```

**this is my index page**

```
    async fetch() {
      ........
        this.headValue = {
          title: this.pageData?.value?.title,
          link: [
            {
              rel: 'canonical',
              href: `https://flyver.ir`,
            },
          ],
          meta: [
            {
              name: 'description',
              content: this.pageData?.value?.description,
            },
            
            ...this.pageData?.metaTags,
          ],
        };
        ..........
      },
      head() {
        return this.headValue;
      },
```

**What is Expected?**
I expect the meta tags that are created per page to be added to the global meta tags

**What is actually happening?**
Replaces new meta tags with global meta tags

Comment: Can you please try with `asyncData` rather than `fetch`?

Comment: No, unfortunately, I can't. Do you have another way?

Comment: Can't try with `asyncData` even for testing purposes?

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work with this method. I think that when we put the meta information in the head, the previous information will be deleted


Do you have an opinion?